# How can I configure a shell script which will parse ldap data in ldif format for each dn:

Tags: bash, ldap-query

I have a LDIF database something like this.

```
dn: uid=user1,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
mail: user1@example.com
passwordexpirationtime: 20120113203000Z

dn: uid=user2,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
mail: user2@example.com
passwordexpirationtime: 20120113203000Z

dn: uid=user3,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
mail: user3@example.com
passwordexpirationtime: 20120113203000Z
```

How can I configure a shell script to parse each dn: check the value of passwordexpirationtime, compare it with current date. if less then 10 days then send a mail to value in mail attribute ?

If I search the value of attribute by `grep passwordexpirationtime |awk -F ':' '{print $2}'` It will return value for all dn: how will I know which mail: is associated by which dn:

Answer (score 1):

you can tell awk to split the input by different separators:

```
BEGIN { RS="\n\n"; FS="\n" }
```

that way it'll split the records as blocks and the fields as lines, then you can get the third field of each record, strip the date and compare it.

but if you have a python script to check the date, why don't you just do it all in python?

Comment: Yes,using awk would be more easy.cat ldif.txt | awk 'BEGIN { RS="\n\n"; FS="\n" } {print $1}'

Comment: Python - Because I dont know anything about programming, Just copy/paste & changing as per my need. @tinychen You idea worked. I will give awk thingy a try.. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You could transform the text like this:

mail: user1@example.com passwordexpirationtime: 20120113203000Z

mail: user2@example.com passwordexpirationtime: 20120113203000Z

mail: user3@example.com passwordexpirationtime: 20120113203000Z

use this scripts:

cat ldif.txt | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/||/\n/g' | awk -F"|" '{print $2,$3}'

Comment: wonderful, I can do {print $1,$2,$3} & then read use awk to read value of passwordexpirationtime, compare it with today (I have a python script for the same.) if 1 comes use mail attribute and send mail. else move on second record. Thanks a lot Will try this tonight & update the results.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
awk '{print $4,$6}' RS='' ldif.txt
user1@example.com 20120113203000Z
user2@example.com 20120113203000Z
user3@example.com 20120113203000Z
```

Now all you have to do is add some date arithmetic, like so:

```
awk '{if(systime()+(10*24*60*60)-mktime(gensub(/(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(.)/,"\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5 \\6 \\7",1g,$6))>0)print $4}' RS='' ldif.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a solution in python, since that seems to be the language you're using:

```
with open('ldif.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('passwordexpirationtime'):
            _, date = line.split(': ')
            print date
```